# layout_height always wrapping content

Tags: android, android-layout

it's just a simple question:

I have a layout file which is presented as an item inside of a ListView. I set the height of the RelativeLayout to 100dp, but it does not work, it's always wrapping the content, no matter which layout I use. What can I do to set a fixed value to the layout height without having it wrapping?

Thanks for the help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"> <!-- this attribute seems to be ignored -->

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_width="@dimen/progressbar_small"
                 android:layout_height="@dimen/progressbar_small"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                 android:text="@string/loading"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                 style="@style/ListItemSubtext" />

     </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try adding a background to the RelativeLayout just so you can be sure it is actually wrapping, also try increasing your height to say 200dips to see what happens.

Comment: A good tool for debugging layouts is the heirarchy viewer, in the tools folder.  It might help show you what is driving what.

Comment: Faria Also, what is your desired behavior?  Maybe you should put it all in a scroll view with height 100?  I'm not really sure why you would want a layout with part of it cutoff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think in a list view all items are of the same height. In your case you could add the progress bar in the list footer view. Add a dummy height adjuster right before or after ListItemSubtext. Try using TableLayout instead of Relative and Linear Layout.

A dummy adjuster is like this.

```
<View android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="100dip"/>
```

Please note you do not need xmlns in every element.

Answer (score 6):

Do like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="100dip">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just using 100px. Works for me.

Comment: Try applying the same height restriction to all of the nested views. Also, this is a tangent, but you don't need the LinearLayout in the xml you are showing.

Comment: You should never use px values.  This will cause bad behavior on phones of different sizes. See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @Flavio: Regardless, I think your problem resides in that you inner view are larger than the area you gave them in the RL. I believe that by making the size standard, it should work.

Comment: If I apply that for the children views, they will be bigger than what I want. I want them the size they are, with the list item spanning through 100dp. I'm using LinearLayout to centralize the pair progressbar/textview horizontally.

Comment: No, the inner view height is just the size of a small text. When I try to set a much bigger value than 100dp, it makes no difference. I think the problem is because this layout is being set to a ListView item. The ListView does not allow me to set the height I want.

Answer (score 0):

i do below changes in your xml..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"> <!-- this attribute taking a fixed value as u said -->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
             android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
             android:layout_width="20dip" 
             android:layout_height="20dip"/>

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
             android:text="@string/loading"
             android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
             style="@style/ListItemSubtext" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

If this doesn't work for you, say what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Thank you, debarati. Check the screenshots below. The first one shows a list with a "loading" item in the end. The XML I posted corresponds to the XML of this loading item. The second screenshot shows what happens when I change the XML the way you suggested. It's not that what I want. What I want is to increase the height of the list item without increasing the size of the textView or progressbar. I thought the only way to do that would be increasing the height of the outer viewgroup. If I change from 100dp to 500 or 1000dp or any higher value, the list item keeps with the same size.